# setFormula() in a FormResponse Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I am using GAS to generate a Google Form via Google Sheets. After the Form is generated and the "Responses" tab is added to the Sheet, the script adds a formula to cell E1 that is just supposed to copy the Timestamp from the A column to the E column. It looks like this:

```
ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("E1").setFormula("={\"Timestamp Moved\"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A<>\"\",$A$2:$A,\"\"))}");
```

And shows this in the cell:
={"Timestamp Moved"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A<>"",$A$2:$A,""))}

The formula drops into place just fine and looks right when I go to the Sheet and click on E1. However, whenever the Form is submitted, the "A$2:$A" moves down one row. So after the first submission, the formula in E1 changes to:

```
={"Timestamp Moved"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$3:$A<>"",$A$3:$A,""))}
```

And so on. However, if I go into E1 and manually type the formula `={"Timestamp Moved"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A<>"",$A$2:$A,""))}` it works just fine. The A2 will stay A2 across all submissions.

The setFormula function is only running once, so it isn't like the GAS script is updating it. Any ideas why it is moving itself down?

**EDIT**
To minimally reproduce this, open GAS from within a Google Sheet and add this script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("C1").setFormula("={\"Timestamp Moved\"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF($A$2:$A<>\"\",$A$2:$A,\"\"))}");
}
```

Next, from within the Sheet, select "Tools" and "Create a new form". Make a one question Form, then run the script. Go to the Responses tab and you should see this:
[image: 1]

Then, fill out the Form once and you will now see this:
[image: 2]

The timestamp is not moved and the formula shifts.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue but the range in formula didn't change. Have you tried removing the $ in your setFormula? Also, could you provide a sample screenshot of the form and the form responses in the sheets?

Comment: @NikkoJ., I edited my original post. See if that helps.

Comment: I tried it on an existing sample with existing answers, and the formula did not change when I posted a new answer. Maybe this happens in a completely new form.

Comment: I think the problem is that new answers are added by inserting rows, which causes cell references to be updated automatically. You could prevent it with INDIRECT like so: `ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("E1").setFormula("={\"Timestamp Moved\"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT(\"$A$2:$A\")<>\"\",INDIRECT(\"$A$2:$A\"),\"\"))}");`

Answer (score 1):

Google form response is inserted right after the row of the last response.

So the range changes from `A2:A` tp `A3:A`.

You should either add the formula after there is a response in row 2,

or use `INDIRECT("A2:A")` instead of `A2:A`.